# How do I deploy Windows applications written in MonoDevelop?

Tags: .net, deployment, installation, windows-installer, monodevelop

I'm currently on the end of a trial of Visual Sudio 2010 and I started using MonoDevelop a bit. It looks to have most of the functionality I need, so I'm hoping to migrate to it. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to create an installer for my solution. Is there a plug-in or option I missed that will allow me to create an MSI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not supported directly in MonoDevelop (for MSI).  There is a [current development project for reworking the Packaging system](http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Tasks/Packaging/Packaging_Projects_Overhaul), including support for WiX, which would allow this.

Currently, the best option would be to use an external project for building your deployment.  [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) and [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) are both good options.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you are going to find that kind of functionality.  You could use [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) on the command line.

Also, if you are still experimenting with IDE's there is always [SharpDevelop](http://www.sharpdevelop.net/opensource/sd/).  It supports WiX and .Net development.